# How to compare values in a column of the same file based on the common entries in another column

Tags: awk

In my file, every entry in `$1` is duplicated, but the values in `$2` are unique. I want to compare the corresponding values in `$3` for each duplicate pair, and then if the `$3` value is bigger, do `awk {print $1,$2}` for the corresponding row:

```
File

A    ND       1
B    NE       6
C    NF       2
A    ND_upd   10
B    NE_upd   3
C    NF_upd   7
```

Desired output:

```
A    ND_upd
B    NE
C    NF_upd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have each duplicated entry in column1 occurring only twice then the following should suffice:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '
($1 in compare) { print ($3 > compare[$1] ? $1 OFS $2 : line[$1]); next }
                { compare[$1] = $3; line[$1] = $1 OFS $2 }
' file
```

If the column1 can be duplicated more than 2 times then you will need to build an array keeping the max for each duplicated entry and print them all in the `END` block.

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '
($1 in compare) {
    if ($3 > compare[$1]) {
        compare[$1] = $3
        line[$1] = $1 OFS $2
    }
    next
}
{
    compare[$1] = $3; 
    line[$1] = $1 OFS $2
    key[++idx] = $1
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<=idx; i++) print line[key[i]]
}' file
```

**Output:** In both cases

```
A   ND_upd
B   NE
C   NF_upd
```

Comment: Note that the first will potentially mix up the order a little (if that matters). If the order doesn't matter, the second could be simplified: `awk '{if ($3>max[$1]) {max[$1]=$3; f2[$1]=$2}} END{for(i in max) print i, f2[i]}'`

Comment: @ooga Thanks, I assumed ordered input as given in OPs sample for both solutions but I explicitly handled the order in second solution as using the `in` operator in the `END` block could have messed up the order.